# How to handle CORS error in Angular JS .

Tags: angularjs, cross-browser, cors, cross-domain

How to handle CORS  error in Angular JS . I used CORS tool in chrome and fixed the issue, Any chance to handle it in frontend without using CORS tool . I don't want to make any change in backend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUCmn.png)

Answer (score 0):

CORS is a built-in browser security feature. Modern browsers use CORS to determine whether they have been given access to access a certain resource.

Turning it off is a hack. Using a CORS tool in chrome isn't fixing the issue at all, it's monkey-patching it so that it works on your development machine.

You'll have to read up on how to configure CORS on the server side. For a safe application CORS is not optional, and it is in your company's interests to implement it, but unfortunately it's beyond the scope of the question for me to tell you how to do that here.

Alternatively, you could configure your application and your backend to work with **JSONP**, CORS's older cousin. CORS is generally preferred to JSONP because JSONP only supports GET requests, but it may be easier to set up in your circumstance.